How does the Wigner-Seitz sphere tell you the volume of ions versus electrons in a sample?
I am working in the classical Drude model. Consider some sample of an alkali metal. The Wigner-Seitz sphere is defined as
$$\frac{4\pi}{3}r_{WS}^3 := \frac{V}{N}$$
where $N$ is the number of atoms in the sample and $V$ is the volume of a sample. How does knowing the numerical value of $r_{WS}$ tell me what fraction of the volume of the sample is taken up by ions?

You have many typoes. It is V on top and N below, if only just to be dimensionally correct. There is no cube on the $\pi$. Which source is making that claim? It is clearly supposed to be a rough estimate.

@naturallyInconsistent oops typos fixed. source: Solyom & Piroth Fundamentals of the Physics of Solids vol. 2.
